# tcpdump - No connection and strange packets (oui unknown, ethertype Unknown (0x22f4))

Tags: networking, tcpdump, xen

I have a Xen Server which got a new NIC recently. The Xen Server got deleted from the pool, the interfaces got new IDs as per documentation and the server was re-inserted.

Since then, I cannot connect to on some of the interfaces as I was used to. The interfaces in question were used to connect to our Storage Servers.

Even after searching the interwebs for quite some time, I am confused of the configuration, as there seems to be a vlan on the other side of the interfaces. But that vlan isn't configured on the Xen Server. Still, the same configuration is present on other servers, where it seems to work.

What confuses me the most are the following messages, captured on eth4, which is a bridge (xenbr4), with its own IP:

```
[root@xensrv01~]# tcpdump -vv -i eth4
tcpdump: WARNING: eth4: no IPv4 address assigned
tcpdump: listening on eth4, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
10:10:48.175669 
10:10:49.359977 STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Learn, Forward], bridge-id 80c8.<bridge-id>.8009, length 43
    message-age 2.00s, max-age 20.00s, hello-time 2.00s, forwarding-delay 15.00s
    root-id 80c8.<root-id>, root-pathcost 6, port-role Designated
10:10:49.581931 <mac-1> (oui Unknown) > <mac-2> (oui Unknown), ethertype Unknown (0x22f4), length 125: 
    0x0000:  831b 0106 0f01 0001 01cc 3e5f 1422 a001  ..........>_."..
    0x0010:  2c00 6f40 cc3e 5f14 22a0 0401 0201 0081  ,.o@.>_.".......
    0x0020:  01c0 8f3d 0000 0108 0004 e0ec c001 0001  ...=............
    0x0030:  0203 0000 4002 0301 b880 0205 0708 dfff  ....@...........
    0x0040:  d803 1ee0 ec00 0100 01e0 ec01 b801 b8e0  ................
    0x0050:  ec07 0807 09e0 ec07 0b07 19e0 ec07 1b07  ................
    0x0060:  1c91 01c0 d309 0000 0000 0000 0000 00    ...............
10:10:50.392126 <mac-3> (oui Unknown) > Broadcast, ethertype Unknown (0x9001), length 64: 
    0x0000:  0201 000b 0001 0000 0002 0000 0000 0000  ................
    0x0010:  0000 0000 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
    0x0020:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1600 0000 0000  ................
    0x0030:  0840                                     .@
```

This is pretty much all you can see on the interface. It doesn't seem to appear on any other of the six servers we have.

What does this mean? Is my NIC broken (again)?

I would appreciate some insight into this, as I have no idea where to look anymore and have spent a considerable amount of time already. I can provide any additional necessary information.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, it came down to two things:

1. Having the right cables connect the right ports with each other X)
2. Deleting and re-creating the network bridge

This made me have network connectivity again and the errors above stopped. I did this via the Xen Center though, which made all VMs running in the pool not have a connection for some time. Not recommended ;-)

I am still trying to find out how to re-create just the bridge on one xen host, not on all of them.